# como mostrar un mensaje de error en el login de devise, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Devise me coloca sus respectivos errores en todas sus vistas, excepto en la de login cuando un usuario introduce mal sus datos. solo me redirigi a la misma vista, sin mostrar un mensaje de error

Answer (score 0):

Debes asegurarte que estas imprimiendo las variables `notice` y `alert` en las vistas html.

Para asegurarte de que esto suceda en todas las vistas puedes poner el siguiente código en `views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
```

***Nota:*** si estas utilizando scaffold para generar los modelos tendras que eliminar la etiqueta `<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>` en el `index.html.erb` para que no se repita el mensaje en esa vista
`